# is there a way to quickly convert Json<Value> to bson to be able to save it to mongo?

Tags: json, mongodb, rust, bson

I have `Json<Value>` object (from `serde_json::Value`) with no Rust struct (because objects have quite many properties and it may change) and I would like to convert it to `mongodb::Document` or `bson` to save it to mongo, is there any integration or should I write transformer myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serde_json::Value` implements `Serialize` so just use [`bson::to_bson`](https://docs.rs/bson/1.2.2/bson/ser/fn.to_bson.html), or [`bson::to_document`](https://docs.rs/bson/1.2.2/bson/ser/fn.to_document.html)

```rust
let value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::json!({"foo": "bar"});
let bson_value = bson::to_bson(&value);
```